# How is input sanitized in the SOFU World?

Tags: discussion, architecture, xss

Is the sanitizer that keeps us safe from nefarious things like `<script>alert('evil here');</script>` public/available?

Comment: See also: [MarkdownSharp — Not a complete rip from Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95821/markdownsharp-not-a-complete-rip-from-stack-overflow/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 2009, [this was how it was done](http://web.archive.org/web/20090318053325/http://refactormycode.com/codes/333-sanitize-html).

It'd be nice to know if Jeff has updated the public version since then; there are 53 refactorings, but none by Jeff Atwood.

Comment: errr.. it's at the top of the page! text -- UPDATED: July 11th to reflect all refactorings, plus optimizing for speed. Now 2x faster! ; UPDATED: Sept 1st, bugfixes ; UPDATED: May 14th, simplify and improve whitelist strictness