# Was MarkdownSharp made by the SO team?

Tags: support, markdown

What the question says.

And regardless of the answer, is it the same as the one hosted here:
http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/

?

Comment: See the blog: [Introducing MarkdownSharp](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/introducing-markdownsharp/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the fist part of the question, the code is reported to be under copyright of Jeff Atwood (2009-2011); it is visible in the fist lines of the source code (in the initial comment). The last commits done in the code hosted on Google are done by balpha.
For the second part of the question, it is not the same, as there are extensions used on Stack Exchange that are not included in MarkdownSharp.

Comment: Extensions? Like what? (excluding TeX/Math)

Comment: @Null: please see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95821/markdownsharp-not-a-complete-rip-from-stack-overflow (details on how SE does it straight from the horse's mouth)

Comment: That copyright statement, if indeed present, surprises me a bit, as things [originated from another project](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/introducing-markdownsharp/).

Comment: (As an aside: why the line breaks [rather than regular paragraphs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45617/why-you-should-press-return-key-2-times-to-insert-a-new-line/45635#45635)?)

Comment: @arjan this is covered here http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/introducing-markdownsharp/