# some text of the question doesnt appear while edit

Tags: support, stack-overflow, questions

i came across this question on SO [how to get the screenshot of a minimized application programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773398/how-to-get-the-screenshot-of-a-minimized-application-programmatically)

the question is

[image]

so i wanted to edit it,
but on click of [Edit -Question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/773398/edit)

The `Howdy guys,` disappears

[image]

Is it by design or it happening to me only

as i wanted to remove the `Howdy guys,`

This answer by [Jeff Atwood♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/176291) i think removes it, but only from editing?

Answer (score 1):

Markdown is converted into HTML and cached (aka [cooked, pre-cooked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/95821/markdownsharp-not-a-complete-rip-from-stack-overflow/95838#95838)) when saving. This makes showing the post much quicker.

The [automatic removal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/176291) you're referring to, has been introduced after that post was last saved, but the existing cooked HTML was not deleted then. Hence, editing it will trigger the automatic removal that did not exist before.

Just save the post and it will re-create the cached HTML.

Comment: +1, for the information..i though it was some problem here only