# Editing a question automatically removes "Hello"

Tags: bug, editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Edit source differs from question view? Or are we each other's friends now?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123981/edit-source-differs-from-question-view-or-are-we-each-others-friends-now)
>   [some text of the question doesnt appear while edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141474/some-text-of-the-question-doesnt-appear-while-edit)

I was about to edit the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5579436/697449):

[image: question]

After I clicked to edit, I noticed the word "Hello" had disappeared:

[image]

Is this a feature (perhaps some kind of automagic quality filter), or a bug?

I tried searching meta about this but could only find posts about editing policy, like [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is done automatically.  See [Jeff's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/1288) on the post you linked to.  In addition to automatically removing salutations when a post is submitted, they're also automatically removed when you pull them up in the editor.

Comment: +1 Ah interesting - looks like I'm guilty of not reading closely enough (and forgetting to sort answers by votes). Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 4):

I believe there was a bug where the 'baked' version of a post was cached and later edits to the post were thus not visible; this only applies to older posts.

I've edited the post (capitalized the 'I's and removed the salutation) to clear that cache.