# When I enter a SE question URL into a new question, sometimes it is replaced by the title. Sometimes not. Why is this?

Tags: support, hidden-features

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What limitations does converting question links to links with titles have?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108134/what-limitations-does-converting-question-links-to-links-with-titles-have)

Here is what I do not understand. When I first ask a question if I want to include a reference to another question, it seems all I need to do is add the URL for the question.

For example, when I add the text `https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/147712` to this question it becomes: [FAQ for Stack Exchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/147712)

No markdown needed, the link just gets ... dereferenced?? (I am not sure what the correct terminology is.) That is sooo nifty, neat, and cool.

So why does it not work when I edit a question? Under what circumstances is it intended to work? When is it not intended to work?

---

Here is a link to a question where this feature did **not** work for me: [How can I move a discussion from comments to chat after the 'move this discussion to chat' link has disappeared?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/3095/52923)

(But it is still working in this question. My head is beginning to hurt.)

---

**Reply to comment from *BoltClock's a Unicorn*:**

The `preview` always appears to exactly match what you will get. That is, if the title for the link is shown in `preview` then that is what you get when post/save the question. If all you see in `preview` is the URL, then that's all your gonna get unless you dress it up with markdown.

Comment: Does it not show in the preview but it does when you submit the edit? Or something else?

Comment: Ooh, found it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108475/

Comment: you must be using Firefox , am I Correct ?

Comment: @Lucifer No, Chrome 18.0.1025.168 actually.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Added a reply to the question. (But I have to add a comment to notify you that I updated the question. This makes sense? But I digress ...)

Comment: @waiwai933 Thanks! I **never** would have found that on my own. (I had no idea what to search for.)

Comment: Oh, finding stuff on Meta is terrible. The only reason I found it was because I knew I'd seen it before, and since I knew the rules of when it worked were too complicated to recall from memory, finding it was the only option. :)