# Word wrap bug in question titles on new meta.SE theme

Tags: bug, design, meta, title

One of [my meta.SE questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230551/concerns-about-my-downvoting-with-comment-on-established-users-posts-as-a-moder) was just edited, making the title longer in the process. Turns out it was too long, and the text doesn't wrap: it gets cut off.

[image]

On questions with [really, really long titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132329/when-i-enter-a-se-question-url-into-a-new-question-sometimes-it-is-replaced-by) the wrap works, so I'm guessing it's just some small error in estimating the text length.

Comment: (it's not immediately obvious but this is the general case of the above IE-specific issue)

Comment: @TimStone Oh, interesting! I suppose I should add "Mac OSX, Chrome".

Comment: @TimStone This is totally caused by the retarded padding on the title - applies to all browsers, not just IE.

Comment: @animuson Yeah, that's what I said! (in less plain language :P)