# Adding a meta question link in a meta question doesn't resolve question title in preview, but does in actual post

Tags: bug, status-norepro, hyperlinks, per-site-meta, markdown-preview

Best described with images:

### When Editing

[image: Editing]

### Actual Post

[image]

(Highlighting by me).

This also applies when editing the post after it was posted.

Comment: Regression of [this bug](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236344/stack-exchange-url-anchor-text-in-posts-are-no-longer-being-converted-to-link-ti).

Comment: any more details? [seems to work here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hPDnY.png)

Comment: @m0sa What more details do I need? I'll be happy to provide.

Comment: @SecondRikudo can you paste the response from the [chrome/ff devtools network tab](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AYX0x.png) you get to the `api.stackexchange.com/2.0/questions/212?...` call?

Comment: @m0sa Odd, a Schrodinger thing, I guess. When I loaded the window with the debugger open, it made the request (`/**/apiCallbacks.meta$anime$stackexchange$com({"items":[{"last_activity_date":1404509789,"question_id":212,"title":"Should we have separate tags for the Dragon Ball series?"}]});`) and I do see title resolved.