# Which site to ask Scrum questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I asked a question on stackoverflow.com which I thought was similar enough to other Agile/Scrum questions that it was OK but it was put on hold and deleted.

Could someone please advise me where I should post [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010078/sprint-interference-chart-and-capacity?noredirect=1#comment38901328_25010078)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think your best bet is [Project Management](http://pm.stackexchange.com).

Specifically from their [tour page](https://pm.stackexchange.com/tour):

> Ask about...
>
> - Methodologies such as Agile, Scrum or PRINCE2

Comment: Fantastic, thank you.