# How to cite another question in iOS?

Tags: support, ios-app

Is there a way in the iOS app to cite another question?  I can quote the title, but will that automatically create the link?  I would hope not, since that would result in links that were not intended.

- App Version: 1.6.3.6
- Device: iPad Air 2 (Cellular)
- OS Version: Version 10.2.1 (Build 14D27)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the bottom of each question there is a Share button that you can use to then Copy (the URL of the question) and paste a URL into another post.

Copy/pasting links within (and between some) sites will automatically expand to display their title.

Comment: Got it.  Didn't notice that before.  Auto-converting a link to it's title is good.  The opposite would not be good, as it would be too easy to say something that just happens to also be a title.

Comment: "and between some" it's only here (MSE) that cross-site links expand isn't it?

Comment: @Cai From a quick test Ask Question at [gis.se] just now it looks like questions on that site and its child Meta expand but those from Stack Overflow and Meta SE do not, but I thought I had seen some other cross-site links expand in the past too.

Comment: @Cai This Meta SE Q&A suggests that more cross-site linking may have been present in the past, even if not now: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108134

Comment: Oh yeh, site to/from that site's meta definitely expand. I was pretty sure MSE was the only exception to that, I can't find anything confirming that now though.

Comment: Ah yes, seems there are (or were) more :)