# If there are more than 200 internal links in a post, only the first 200 display question titles

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, hyperlinks, internal-links

When you post [an answer](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7058/178988) with more then 200 internal links, only the first 200 are automatically converted to show question titles. All internal links after the first 200 just display the URL.

Comment: Hmmm... If this was by design, I'd expect it to be listed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/108475/323179).

Comment: @Laurel That post does mention 5 and 40... The product is 200. Perhaps they went from "at most 40 links for at most 5 sites" to "at most 200".

Comment: @Laurel balpha cleary said "Links to questions on the same site are unlimited" in that answer, so this is a bug.

Comment: @Sha that post mentions main links on meta in the section about "other sites", which implies they count as other sites... it's a bit ambiguous though so not sure. Either way it's not working as that post says

Comment: @Cai oh, good point. Hopefully the high score here will draw attention of a developer. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard do meta and main sites considered same?

Comment: @alexolut Meaning?

Comment: @SonicWizard see Shadow’s first comment. Links posted on meta site refer to main site, so I asked are they same to be unlimitedly supported.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those aren't internal links. The answer sits on meta.ru.stackoverflow.com; the links point to ru.stackoverflow.com. Those are separate sites with separate databases and every title lookup has to go through the API [as balpha explains here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108134/what-limitations-does-converting-question-links-to-links-with-titles-have/108475#108475) (hat-tip Laurel for the reference).

The limit for cross-site lookups for posts on a meta site is 200 (has been since 2012, but not consistently documented).

Comment: I've always thought that main site and meta considered as the same site...