# Is there an easy way to post nice hyperlinks to questions?

Tags: feature-request, markdown, hyperlinks

Often I want to link to an existing question on the SE network in a comment or even a question/answer. One way to do this is by using the `Share` button. The link will be given in the form `https://stackexchange-site.com/q/question-id/user-id`, and you can simply post it. But the result doesn't look nice or at least informative enough when compared to the links created by the automated *"Possible duplicate of XYZ"* posts when casting *Close As Duplicate* votes.

To simulate the links from the "Possible duplicate" posts one needs to

1. On the question page, get the share link
2. Switch to the page where the link is to be posted
3. Type `[](the-link-you-copied)` in the text entry field
4. Switch back to the question page
5. Try to select the caption, avoiding dragging it (since it's a hyperlink)
6. Copy it
7. Switch to the page where the link is to be posted
8. Paste the caption between the `[]` you've typed

That's inconvenient. Is there an easier way to do this? If not, I'd like to request one of the following

- A Markdown-formatted link in the format `[Question Caption?](https://question-url)` as a possible format in the *Share* popup (Imgur does something similar when you upload an image);
- Automatic transformation of the links like `https://stackoverflow.com/q/question-id/...` and similar with other SE domains into hyperlinks with the caption of the question linked to (we already have the *Linked* panel, but it lacks context);
- Something other, if the options above are not good enough.

Comment: There is some support for this in questions and answers already, for some details see [What limitations does converting question links to links with titles have?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108134/295232). (*yes, I had to construct that link manually. So +1 for this feature request*)

Comment: @Glorfindel [What limitations does converting question links to links with titles have? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108134/what-limitations-does-converting-question-links-to-links-with-titles-have) no construction required. See my answer ;)

Comment: If you hold down the Alt key while selecting from a hyperlink, it won't treat it as a hyperlink. (In Firefox at least; doesn't work in Edge.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton although it works (tested in Chromium), it interferes with "drag the window" functionality of my window manager. I have to disable Alt+drag function to select hyperlink text this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use @JasonC's [More Share Links (Markdown / HTML / BBCode)](https://stackapps.com/q/7403) userscript as a workaround.

The userscript creates additional fields in the standard Stack Exchange share dialog:

[image: More share links]

For some reason, it didn't work for me right away and I had to fix a couple of things. I've uploaded an updated script on Github:

- [Source code](https://github.com/defaultlocale/userscripts/blob/master/MoreShareLinks.user.js)
- [Installation link](https://github.com/defaultlocale/userscripts/raw/master/MoreShareLinks.user.js)

You'll probably need to install a userscript manager browser extension (e.g. [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/)) first.

Comment: This actually directly addresses my first bullet point, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

#### Is there an easier way to do this?

I use a FireFox extension for this called [Copy as Markdown](https://github.com/chitsaou/copy-as-markdown).

To get the link for **this** question:

- Right Click (outside of the edit box)
- Select "Copy [Page Title](URL)"
- Paste from clipboard

[image]

Result:

[Is there an easy way to post nice hyperlinks to questions? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330946/is-there-an-easy-way-to-post-nice-hyperlinks-to-questions).

Another couple of mouse clicks to add attribution:

Asked by [Ruslan](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/226705/ruslan).

There is a version of this extension for Chrome as well (I haven't tried it).

> Features:
>
> Copy as Markdown is a browser extension helps you copy the following
>   things as Markdown to your system clipboard:
>
> - Current Tab as Link
> - A Link in the Page
> - An Image in the Page
> - An Image that is wrapped with a Link
> - All Tabs as a List of Links
> - Highlighted Tabs as a List of Links

Source [chitsaou/copy-as-markdown: Copying Link, Image and Tab(s) as Markdown Much Easier.](https://github.com/chitsaou/copy-as-markdown)

Comment: That looks like a good workaround. You won't get the [Announcer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/54/announcer) badge for such links though :P

Comment: @Ruslan There only one [badge](https://superuser.com/help/badges/45/legendary) I'm actually chasing and care about and it's not Announcer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you place the link copied from *share* on its own line, it will be formatted nicely.

- [Is there an easy way to post nice hyperlinks to questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330946/286574)

Comment: I guess it won't work in comments. Checking:

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330946/226705

Comment: @Ruslan I guess not. But it’s the most convenient by far in a Q/A post.