# A bare meta URL was not auto-linked

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, auto-linking

As you may know, bare links within the network are converted to linked titles when they meet the requirements in [What limitations does converting question links to links with titles have?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/108134/323179). However, I noticed that the answer to [What is the Minimum Number of Candidates?](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5760/41273) contained a bare link (`https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135360/295232` which is [There's an election going on. What's happening and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135360/295232)) that wasn't automatically converted. I edited it to "fix" that, after which I realized that the original revision was displaying properly in the revision history (so I rolled it back). The post now autolinks properly.

I wasn't the only one who saw it happen:

- > The URL didn't expand for me the first time I looked at it as well. – ColleenV
- > Wasn't rendering for me until after the edit either (can confirm the auto-title works now). – Oleg Valter is with Ukraine

Comment: I suspect it's something to do with the new editor. Perhaps they now transmit the client-rendered HTML to the server rather than doing the render server-side to prevent things unexpectedly changing in case the server-side renderer renders the post differently from the client preview.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog the Stacks Editor isn't live on ELL.Meta yet. For the record, I don't remember anymore how the post looked like when I created it. I tend not to look at the preview (or the outcome after posting) unless I'm not sure about some formatting I used, and I know auto-expansion of Meta.SE links is supposed to work on child metas.

Comment: This sounds like it was an intermittent failure to parse the URL or fetch the post title.Given the general issues that SE sites have been experiencing, I'd just chalk this up to a "one-off" issue and leave it. If it's something which is repeatable, or which repeats, then it's probably something to look into.

Comment: @Makyen is most likely correct indeed, the conversion is done when the post is submitted, as a "side job", which if failing should not stop the post from being submitted. Instead, if there's error during the link conversion, it's using the link itself.